# How can I determine on the server-side when an incoming request is HTTPS?

Tags: http, https

Is there a HTTP environment variable I can use to work this out?

Comment: There are no HTTP environment variables, but the server usually sets some. To give an answer, we need to know what server / platform / server-side language you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using at server side.
If you are using java servlet then you can get URL information as follow:

```
String scheme = request.getScheme();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int portNumber = request.getServerPort();
```

Comment: I looked deeper into the Request object in my environment and there is a secure flag set on the Request object - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apache sets an [`HTTPS` environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) to the value 1 or "on" when the request was made trough SSL. Note that this flag is not present on simple HTTP requests.